# Is it possible to get a UITableView's body?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I'd like to add a view on top of just the scrollable part of a UITableView which does not cover the header or the footer.

Edit: I am trying to put a transparent gray overlay + activity spinner on top of the table section while the data is loading, but I don't want to cover the banner. I know I could find the frame of the banner and create a UIView that starts at the bottom of it, but it seems like I should have a reference to the scrollable UIView that is the table's body.

Comment: You mean a view that is fixed and sits above the table view so it doesn't scroll?

Comment: I just edited my question to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use the Refresh Control (iOS 6+)? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH9-SW11

Comment: The refresh control, AFAIK, is for refreshing the table. I am allowing the user to select different options from a menu which will populate the table with different things, depending on their selection. When they select another category of things I put a loading spinner and overlay on top of the table, but do not want it to cover the table header.

Comment: If you want your view to be scrollable, you should add it to the table as a section (without a header, or without rows). And if you don't want it to be scrollable you should add your `view` in a view, and your tableview starting at the bottom of your `view`.

Comment: @BigCheesy: I would recommend using some type of progress HUD, like https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD

Comment: I just need to know how to get a reference to the body of a table, so that I can put a view directly on top of it.